# To get a specific value at a specific location using Url indexOf

Tags: javascript, indexof

Url
/product/product/4415/category/44/display/1/

```
var url = location.href;

var getAr0 = url.indexOf("44");

if(getAr0 != -1) {
$("#asideNav-top").addClass("open");
}
```

Try to execute the if statement only when /category/44/.

The problem is when the URL is

Url
/product/product/4415/category/71/display/1/

```
//Even if the above statement is executed.

if(getAr0 != -1) {
$("#asideNav-top").addClass("open");
}
```

What I want is to run the if statement only when /category/44/.

Comment: You give the answer yourself. You need "/category/44", not just "44".

Comment: @JensW I'm sorry. Asked too confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find `/category/44/` but not just `44` like below;

```
var url = location.href;
var getAr0 = url.indexOf('/category/44/');

if(getAr0 != -1) {
  $("#asideNav-top").addClass("open");
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
I think my question is stupid.
So sorry.